# Should Solidity interfaces always specify return types?

Tags: solidity, inheritance, interfaces

I've seen interfaces in which the function definitions specify a return type, ie: 
(from openZepplin's IERC721.sol)

```
function balanceOf(address owner) public view returns (uint256 balance);
```

and sometimes, even in the same interface, you'll see something like:

```
function approve(address to, uint256 tokenId) public;
```

Obviously, it doesn't make sense for `approve` to return a uint. It could, however, return a boolean value:

```
return(bool success)
```

I can see that the absence of a return type in the interface allows more flexibility in how the implementation handles the return value, but are there any other drawbacks/benefits to specifying a return type vs leaving it out of the interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch what happens if they don't match:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract ApproveInterface {
    function approve(address to, uint256 tokenId) public;
}

contract Approve is ApproveInterface {
    function approve(address to, uint256 tokenId) public returns(bool success) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
browser/Interface1.sol:8:5: TypeError: Overriding function return types differ.
    function approve(address to, uint256 tokenId) public returns(bool success) {
    ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
browser/Interface1.sol:4:5: Overriden function is here:
    function approve(address to, uint256 tokenId) public;
    ^---------------------------------------------------^
```

You can define a different function signature that uses different arguments (the function signature is based on a hash) and that will be treated as a completely different function. The compiler doesn't complain.

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract ApproveInterface {
    function approve(address to, uint256 tokenId) public;
}

contract Approve is ApproveInterface {
    uint x;
    function approve(address to, uint256 tokenId, bytes32 other) public {
        x = 1;
    }
}
```

However, it isn't deployable because it's treated as a completely separate function that doesn't override the empty function in the interface. Consequently, the contract has inherited a still-undefined transaction from the interface and therefore cannot be deployed.

To see what I mean, try deploying it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Just for context, this question was prompted by this article: https://medium.com/coinmonks/missing-return-value-bug-at-least-130-tokens-affected-d67bf08521ca